# No Glance or call+SMS filter with Amber

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-920, amber-update, glance

I just bought a new Nokia Lumia 920. It doesn't have Glance or "call+SMS filter", while my own Lumia 920 does have them.

- Bought from an independent shop in Israel, though it appears to have been imported from Italy - box says `Garanzia Italia (...) Nokia Sales international Oy, sede secondaria in Italia, Via Lancetti, 20158 Milano`.
- About says `OS version: 8.0.10326.78`, just like my own phone.
- "Phone updates" finds nothing.
- Nokia's "extras+info" says `Lumia Amber, Application version 1.10.1.17`, while mine says `3.0.6.1`.
- Neither has a Nokia Account defined.

I guess I need to update the Nokia application - how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Lumia Pusher](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=d4ef32ad-b9fc-4150-99ba-94daa08798f4), run it and let it check for the outdated Lumia applications, then update them and everything will be fine.

Comment: Eventually apps update worked, didn't use Lumia Pusher.